# Skipping commit messages on feature branches

Tags: git

Sometimes it's difficult to come up with a good commit message. Let's say I'm working in a feature branch, for a feature I'm working on alone. I'm then interrupted by a coworker who asks me to look at something in a different branch. I would then commit my work and switch to his branch, however the work I've done is not anything specific, so the commit message ends up being something useless like "more work on feature".

Assuming I am working alone on a feature branch, is it acceptable to skip the message when making small commits? Merging the feature into master with `git merge --no-ff -m "[Descriptive commit message]"` will keep the master history pretty, which is the important thing.

Comment: You should learn about `git stash` and `git worktree`.

Answer (score 0):

[Squash your commits](https://blog.github.com/2016-04-01-squash-your-commits/) with `git merge --squash` when merging feature branch into master branch. This will results in a single commit on master branch, keeping the master history pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you *can* skip meaningful commit messages, although it's disputable if that isn't a very bad style. Commit messages are not (only) for others, they're also helping yourself to figure out what you did, i.e. when you worked on a feature for some time and try to figure out what summary to put in the merge/pull request.

How can the work you did be "not anything specific"? You added a property? So it's "Added property xy". You deleted obsolete code? So it's "Deleted obsolete code". How can you do something and afterwards not be able to say what you did?!

Of course, my answer is highly influenced by what my team considers to be a "clean workflow" and can in no way be a universal truth, since many workflows work with git and every team may handle things differently.